# N-Tier Architecture with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, n-tier-architecture

We are following N-Tier Architecture pattern for our ASP.NET web apps. We are using these layers DAL,BAL, Business Objects and Common. Now we are moving to ASP.NET MVC4.

1. Can we still use these N-Tier architecture with MVC?
2. Is that meaningful mixing together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can still use this. Why wouldn't you? It is alway better to sepperate all you layers. Your business layer is only responsible for you business logic. So how would you otherwise share your business logic over two type of clients? Think in a MVC website and WCF service layer or a Mobile application.

We developing in MVC for a long time now and always use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC Architecture in this context is essentially a front end architecture. you should still be able to use all your previous layers. Just understand that the model of the mvc is the point where you would likely "bridge" into your other layers.

So sure, you can keep the separation of concerns in layers form